# Make background fragment not interactable

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently adding a new fragment (using single activity pattern) to my `supportFragmentManager` via `add()` method from another fragment. But my new fragment uses only half of the screen, and I still can interact with the fragment in background. Is there any way to block user interaction with background fragment? Just like DialogFragment do. Also, I cant use dialog fragments cause of [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184664892).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, right after posting a question i looked up in DialogFragment code and found in `onStart()` method this lines:

```
View decorView = mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(decorView, this);
ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(decorView, this);
ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(decorView, this);
```

To make it work in regular fragment i just edited first line to this

```
val view = myRootView as View //View decorView = mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
```

And that's it

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialog fragment for half of screen (Did you use material dialog fragment).
https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc

And you can use Eventbus(https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or SingleEvent ([https://abhiappmobiledeveloper.medium.com/android-singleliveevent-of-livedata-for-ui-event-35d0c58512da#:~:text=LiveData%20notifies%20Observer%20objects%20when,every%20time%20there's%20a%20change.](https://abhiappmobiledeveloper.medium.com/android-singleliveevent-of-livedata-for-ui-event-35d0c58512da#:%7E:text=LiveData%20notifies%20Observer%20objects%20when,every%20time%20there%27s%20a%20change.)) for notify the background fragment

Comment: I need to show fragment on top of the window. Dialog fragment was a perfect choice, but for some reason, in API Level 30 there is a bug(?) with softInputMode in Dialogs.